# Angular directive dependencies

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

Might be a very basic question, but if I am using a particular version of a dependency, for example 1.x of dependency1, in my angular directive, and I package this directive to be used as a third party directive in an app that uses version 2.x of the same dependency1, how will the behavior be? I want to understand how shared directives work with multiple apps that might use a different version of a dependency that the directive is using.

EDIT
I should probably make myself clear that I’m not asking about versions of angular. Let’s say I’m using bootstrap v3.3.7 in my directive whereas another app that uses my directive is using v3.1.1 of bootstrap. I want to understand how this would work and if there would be any conflicts.

Comment: Are you asking about version 1 vs version 2? or Version compatibility for version 2 and up? they are different questions - Angular 2 was re-written from the ground up and is not compatible with version 1.

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully added more clarity

Answer (score 0):

If you want / need to have a hybrid solution between versions I would recommend you have a look at the upgrade section of the documentation.  They explain what you need / can do to have an hybrid solution running angularjs and Angular.

[Angular Docs Upgrade](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)